# How to extract specific values against specific keys in Presto

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

Using Amazon Athena for this with Presto - So I have two columns in the query - one is a string column and the other is a map column (varchar, double).
I want to get the value of the key from the map column if the key in the map column matches the string in the first column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`element_at`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/map#map-functions):

> Returns value for given key, or `NULL` if the key is not contained in the map.

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(key_col, map_col) as (
    values ('key1', map(array['key1', 'key2'], array[1,2])),
           ('key3', map(array['key1', 'key2'], array[1,2]))
)

-- query
select element_at(map_col, key_col)
from dataset;
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 1 |
| NULL |